# Can I set arbitrary EMWH hints with pygtk?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, x11

To be more specific, I'd like to set _NET_WM_STRUT_PARTIAL for a window that gets created by a python script using PyGTK.
If found gtk.gdk.Atom in the documentation but it seems to relate to the selection management.
Any help would be appreciated. Thx in advance.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work, but try [gdk_property_change](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk/unstable/gdk-Properties-and-Atoms.html#gdk-property-change).